# What's the reason for Expression must be a modifiable lvale error in this code?

Tags: c, arrays, char, lvalue

I am new to C and learning about char arrays.Here is my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[4];
    int i = 1;
    if (a[i] = 'a' || a[i] = 'e')

    printf("%c", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to assign twice a char array in the if statement the compiler gives an error: Expression must be a modifiable lvale. I can't understand what is the reason for this error.I thought that in the if statement first a[i] will be assigned a value 'a' then finally 'e'.But it appears it is not like that.Please help me to understand what is the reason for this error.

Answer (score 5):

`(a[i] = 'a' || a[i] = 'e')` will be parsed as `(a[i] = ('a' || a[i]) = 'e')` because `||` has higher precedence than `=` operator.  `||` operator returns either `0` or `1` which are rvalue and not assignable.  Assignments `0 = 'e'` or `1 = 'e'` are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence. `=` is lower priority than `||`.

```
'a' || a[i]
```

is `1` which isn't a modifiable lvalue.